# Powershell lookup for test users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a script working that will look through the entire Active Directory and alert when a user that has the word "test" in it.
I managed to create a code that i think should have worked. when i run powershell ISE as a regular domain admin user, it gives me a result, when i try running ISE as administrator it shows me 0 results. not sure why.

```
# Define the search criteria
$SearchString = "*test*"
$AccountStatus = "Enabled"


try {
   # Search for active users with "test" in their names
    $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $SearchString -and Enabled -eq $true} -Properties SamAccountName

    if ($Users.Count -gt 0) {
        # User accounts found
        Write-Host "Active user accounts found with 'test' in their names."
        Write-Host "Exiting with exit code 1."
        write-host '<-Start Result->'
        write-host "Alert=Test user exists"
        write-host '<-End Result->'
        #exit 1
    } else {
        # No user accounts were found
        Write-Host "No Active user accounts found with 'test' in their names."
        Write-Host "Exiting with exit code 0."
        write-host '<-Start Result->'
        Write-host "Alert=Healthy - Test user does NOT exist"
        write-host '<-End Result->'
       # exit 0
    }
} catch {
    # Error occurred during the search
    Write-Host "An error occurred while searching for user accounts."
    Write-Host "Exiting with exit code 1."
write-host '<-Start Result->'
        Write-host "Alert=Failed Parsing"
        write-host '<-End Result->'
    #exit 1
}
```

Comment: What happens if you create an [mcve] and just do: `Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "*test*"-and Enabled -eq $true} -Properties SamAccountName`?

Comment: I actually worked on this a lot more and ended up achieving my goals using this:
    $Users = (@(Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $SearchString -and Enabled -eq $true} -Properties SamAccountName | select Name, Samaccountname)).count
    $total = if ($users) { $Users.count } else { 0 }
    $diagnostics = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $SearchString -and Enabled -eq $true} -Properties SamAccountName | select Name, Samaccountname
    write-host $users.count
    write-host $total
    if ($total -gt 0) {